# Laravel "many to many" query the relation with "where"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

look at the code first:

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

    public function books() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Book');
    }
}

class Book extends Eloquent {

    public function users() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }
}
```

I want to find some User with a id '1',and get the book name where is equal to something ,like this

```
  User::with(array('Book' => function($query) 
  {
      $query->where('bookname','www')->get();
  }));
```

but it return a user information and the empty array ,
    Users: {
      name: 'xxx',
      xxx: 'xxx',
      books: []
     };

who can help me to fix this issue?  thank you so much !

Comment: why you use `get()` method on inside where query?

Comment: but..with get() or not ,leads to the same query result

Comment: but when I query with 'www11' and others,It works ,I'm so confused

Comment: Do you have your pivot table setup correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$user = User::find($user_id)->books()->where('bookname', '=', 'www')->first();
```

Also these may help you as well:

Grabbing all users with books:

```
$users = User::with('books')->get();
```

Grabbing all users which have books:

```
$users = User::has('books')->get();
```

Grabbing a single user with books:

```
$user = User::with('books')->find($user_id);
```

Comment: I know there is another way: User::find(1)->books()->where('xx','xx')->get()...But I want to use query scope

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use query scope, you may applying join on your specified scope.

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function books() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Book');
    }

    public function scopeByBookName($q, $bookName) {
        return $q->join('user_books as pivot', 'pivot.user_id', '=', 'users_id')
            ->join('books', 'books.id', '=', 'pivot.book_id')
            ->where('books.name', $bookName);
}
```